# How to add another label level to the x-axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, x-axis

I am trying to put a secondary axis on a plot. The first x axis display the day of the month. I would like the label of the secondary axis to be the month name and to be displayed below.

For my first axe I have:

```
plot={}
plot['W']=axs[0]
plot['W'].xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%d'))
plot['W'].xaxis.set_minor_locator(mdates.HourLocator(interval=6))
plot['W'].xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.DayLocator(interval=1))
```

In the end it should look like that[image]:

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, here is one way (*to give you the general logic*) to add the 2nd/lower x-axis with [`twiny`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.twiny.html) :

```py
plot["X"] = axs[1]
plot["X"].plot(dates, vals, "g-")

plot["X"].xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter("%d"))
plot["X"].xaxis.set_minor_locator(mdates.HourLocator(interval=6))
plot["X"].xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.DayLocator(interval=1))

ax2 = plot["X"].twiny()
ax2.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.MonthLocator())
ax2.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter("%b %Y"))

plot["X"].set_xlim(dates[0], dates[-1])
ax2.set_xlim(dates[0]-pd.offsets.MonthBegin(1), dates[-1]+pd.offsets.MonthEnd(1))

ax2.xaxis.tick_bottom()
ax2.spines["bottom"].set_position(("outward", 30))

plt.show();
```

Output :

[image]

*Input used :*

```
np.random.seed(123456)

dates = pd.date_range("20230425", "20230505", freq="2H")
vals = np.random.randn(len(dates), 1)
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. How could I have April written on the left and May on the right?

Comment: I updated the answer, can you check it out ?